# typescript for custom theme styled components

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, typescript-typings, styled-components

I have tried 2 different ways to do this based on some google searches.
I'm trying to setup typing for a custom theme in **typescript expo reactive native project**.
I've setup a declaration ts file and added it to my includes in tsconfig. Here is my setup. Hoping someone out there has went through similar issues and knows how to fix this.

I have a themes folder with the following files that I export out and then import into a index theme file.

```
themes/
  colors
  sizes
  spacing
  index
```

Here is the index file importing from the above theme files.

```
import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components/native";
import { colors } from "./colors";
import { sizes } from "./sizes";
import { spacing, lineHeights } from "./spacing";

const theme: DefaultTheme = {
  colors,
  sizes,
  spacing,
  lineHeights,
};

export default theme;
```

then I have my declaration file which I tried 2 ways one manually adding all the props and the other using typeof.

**types/theme.d.ts**

```
import {} from "styled-components";
import theme from "../themes";

declare module "styled-components" {
  type Theme = typeof theme;
  export interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}

// Manually adding the props.
// import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components/native";

// declare module "styled-components" {
//   export interface DefaultTheme {
//     bg: {
//       primary: string;
//       secondary: string;
//     };
//     sizes: stringp[];
//     lineHeights: {
//       title: string;
//       copy: string;
//     };
//     spacing: string[];
//   }
// }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["types/*"]
    },
  },
  "include": ["./src", "./types"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.test.tsx",
  ]
}
```

Then this is how I'm using this in my tsx app file.

**App.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components/native";
import { Text, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import theme from "./src/themes";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Container>
          <Text>some text</Text>
          <StatusBar />
        </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.bg.primary};
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the approach, but I'm in doubt about this `declare module "styled-components"`, you are importing `DefaultTheme` from `styled-components/native`. Perhaps you should be using that path in `declare module` (BTW I'm using the same approach in a web app and it works)

Comment: Thanks Diego, I imported DefaultTheme into types/theme.d.ts and also changed the  path for "../src/themes"; which is incorrect. But this still doesn't fix it. For example the line  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.bg.primary}; I get the waring on colors where it says "colors does not exist on Default theme ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set `DefaultTheme` in your `themes/index.ts`. It's already used and is just an empty object.

**Update your `themes/index.ts` to this:**

```
import { colors } from "./colors";
import { sizes } from "./sizes";
import { spacing, lineHeights } from "./spacing";

const theme = {
  colors,
  sizes,
  spacing,
  lineHeights,
};

export default theme;
```

**Update your `types/theme.d.ts` this:**

```
import "styled-components"
import theme from "./src/themes";

type ThemeInterface = typeof theme

declare module "styled-components" {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface (this is only necessary if you ur eslint complains. Since it should be and Interface and not a Type.) 
    interface DefaultTheme extends ThemeInterface {}
}
```

And you should be gucci.

Comment: The best answer! I was typing my interface manually. Thanks for this!